# error al enviar correo php

Tags: php

Buenos dias estoy tratando de hacer  un programa que me  envie un correo automaticamente ya e mirado varios foros para ver como solucionar el problema como es cambiar es cambiar el puerto pero no me a funcionado ademas de ver la documentacion en [gihub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1032) pero no he podido solucionar y ya no tengo ideas a ver si algien me puede colcaborar ya verifique la contraseña y el correo 
anexo mi codigo lo estoy probando desde mi pc (localhost)

**Codigo**

```js
<?php

require("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
    require("PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
    require("PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");
 

 $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
 
 
 
$mail->isSMTP();/*Set mailer to use SMTP*/
$mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';/*Specify main and backup SMTP servers*/
$mail->Port = 465 ;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;/*Enable SMTP authentication*/
$mail->Username = "XXXX@gmail.com";/*SMTP username*/
$mail->Password = "******";/*SMTP password*/
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';//*Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted*/
$mail->From = 'XXXX@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = "esteban";
$mail->addAddress( 'XXXX@gmail.com');/*Add a recipient*/
$mail->addReplyTo('XXXX@gmail.com', 'esteban');
/*$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');*/
/*$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');*/
//$mail->WordWrap = 70;/*DEFAULT = Set word wrap to 50 characters*/
//$mail->addAttachment('../tmp/' . $varfile, $varfile);/*Add attachments*/
/*$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');*/
/*$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');*/
$mail->isHTML(false);/*Set email format to HTML (default = true)*/
//$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = "funciona";
//$mail->AltBody = $message;
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   // header("Location: ../docs/confirmSubmit.html");
   echo "funciono";
}
```

**init de php**

```js
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port=25 
smtp_port=25 

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

**Error**

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Si estás ocupando un localhost, tienes que verificar si tu servidor está configurado para poder mandar correos electrtónicos. Con Xampp lo puedes hacer a través de Mercury, solo tienes que configurarlo. Aquí te dejo un video para configurar el Mercury para poder enviar correos por formularios:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1cYlb88GT0